# gmaps url to key code API generator

Tags: api, google-maps, keycode

Does anyone have an idea of where i can set the gmaps API keycode for my application?

i'm using the Gmap including this link src script (maps.google.com/maps?file=api&v=2&key= ..)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/introduction.html#Obtaining_Key

https://code.google.com/apis/console/